# Can a South African V-List ban be removed?

Tags: visas, passports, south-africa, visa-bans, zimbabwean-citizens

Was duped by a conman who presented himself as an Immigration Agent and assisted me on obtaining a Work Visa which I later found out that it was fake. I removed it from my passport but it left a slight mark on the process.

Now when I get to the border, they managed to pick it up that there was something removed and the ban was issued.

My question is: is there by any chance this kind of ban be removed? Also can I travel to other countries without this issue popping up?

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship? Have you replaced your passport since this incident? If *yes*, the answer is most probably that you can travel to other countries that allow you visa-free entry but you would have to declare the ban (which I very much doubt can be lifted) in any visa application that asks about your immigration history. If *no* then IMHO you’re likely to get the same result wherever you go.

Comment: Note that in many countries, deliberately tampering with a passport with intent to use it is an offence punishable by a fine and/or imprisonment eg https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1543

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a Mozambican with a Zimbabwean citizenship. So the passport that was stamped ban is a Zimbabwe passport. I am afraid to travel to South Africa or  to apply for a Visa to travel back to South Africa or abroad as the ban from previous passport might pop up on this new Mozambican passport.

Comment: The ban applies to *you as an individual*, not to your passport. I doubt you’ll be travelling to S Africa any time soon, Immigration would identify you via biometrics.

Comment: i agree with you. Will try maybe after 10 years?

Answer (score 3):

You can uplift the ban but you will need a lawyer and a good reason why they should uplift the ban. But it will cost you some money. Home affairs will need your fingerprints. Normally it takes about 40 days. Best you can do is contact a lawyer. There are many fraud agents.